# Android Gallery View In scroll view-- Gallery not scrolling horizotally

Tags: android, scrollview, gallery

I need to put Gallery View Inside Scrollview It works fine but at run time it does not scrolling in horizontally

I have added it like this

```
 <ScrollView
                android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_below="@+id/btnViewMore"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true" >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical" >

                      <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtProductGalleryTitle"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/rlListView"
                android:layout_alignRight="@+id/rlListView"
                android:layout_below="@+id/rlListView"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/ten_dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Agriculture Produces"
                android:textSize="@dimen/twenty_sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <Gallery
                android:id="@+id/galleryProduct"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/txtProductGalleryTitle"
                android:layout_alignRight="@+id/txtProductGalleryTitle"
                android:layout_below="@+id/txtProductGalleryTitle"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/ten_dp" />
```

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentations](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-cn/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html)

> ScrollView only supports vertical scrolling. For horizontal scrolling, use [HorizontalScrollView](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-cn/reference/android/widget/HorizontalScrollView.html).

**Edit**

Check out these libraries that may help you achieve efficiently what you want.

[DoubleViewPager](https://github.com/juliome10/DoubleViewPager)

[TwoWayView](https://github.com/lucasr/twoway-view)

Comment: no i need gallery that have Horizontal scrolling by default it in to Vertical scrllview

Comment: Check my edit. Upvote and accept my answer if it solves your problem.